# Problem with sending emails in Heroku using Swiftmailer

Tags: symfony, heroku, deployment, gmail, swiftmailer

I wrote an application in symfony 4.
I deployed it on the heroku.
Everything works as it should with the exception of sending emails.
When I trying to send an e-mail from the console like this:

```
heroku run php bin/console swiftmailer:email:Send
```

> Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "healthcard95@gmail.com" using 1 possible authenticat
>   ors. Authenticator LOGIN returned Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 235
>   Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
>   Learn more at  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 i65sm11848023qkh.49 - gsmtp
>   " in /app/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:457

This is my swiftmailer.yaml file:

`swiftmailer:
  transport:        gmail
  username:         username
  password:         ********
  host:             localhost
  port:             465
  encryption:       ssl
  auth-mode:        login
  spool: { type: 'memory' }
  stream_options:
    ssl:
      allow_self_signed: true
      verify_peer: false
      verify_peer_name: false`

How to fix this error?

Comment: Gmail need specific configuration ([symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html#email-using-gmail)).
Are you sure it is not `smtp` you need to use as `transport` ?

Comment: I try it but it doesnt work.
I also changed host to smtp.gmail.com.
But still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Gmail.
Although I have set up security to allow less secure applications and e-mails from local hosts are sent correctly when I perform the same operation in gmail heroku, I see a new device - unfortunately I can't add it to trusted devices, therefore it's blocked.

The solution was to change mail, e.g. on yandex.com.
Here is an example file swiftmailer.yaml correctly configured for heroku:

```html
swiftmailer:
  transport:        smtp
  username:         username
  password:         ********
  host:             smtp.yandex.com
  port:             465
  encryption:       ssl
  auth-mode:        login
  spool: { type: 'memory' }
  stream_options:
    ssl:
      allow_self_signed: true
      verify_peer: false
      verify_peer_name: false
```